# trying to constrain fancybox height

Tags: jquery, css, video, fancybox, height

I want to set up a mixed gallery of images and videos.  Using fancybox, I can constrain the dimensions of an image - but for mp4 video, the height always adjusts to fit the size of my browser window, regardless of the height setting.

[Here's](http://www.59plymouth.net/fancybox/fancybox.html) a working example of just a single video, that demonstrates the problem.  And here's my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popupIframe').fancybox({
        autoDimensions: false,
        padding     : 0,
        width       : 400,
        height      : 300,
        autoScale   : false,
        type        : 'iframe',
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        nextEffect  : 'elastic',
        prevEffect  : 'elastic',
        topRatio    : 0,
        margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60], // Increase left/right margin
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a class="popupIframe" href="/fancybox/media/2.mp4"><img src="/fancybox/media/2_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</body>
```

Comment: *Bump*...  Can I get a clue?

Comment: You may need to set `fitToView` to `false`